# Git pull from source repository, push to separate test repository's directory

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote

I have two git repos, one for the plain source code of a library I'm writing, and the other which acts like a test environment. I'll call them respectively `prod` and `dev`.

Committers pull and push to/from `dev`, and then once `dev` hits a releaseable state, the sub-directory containing the source code is pushed to `prod`. This is done by having `prod` set up as a git submodule in `dev`. That's the easy part.

Now, there's an outside contributor. Someone who pulls in the source code from `prod`, as that's all they need for their project, and they proceed to make it a submodule.

However, I don't want them pushing to prod as that has the risk of screwing something up without it being tested on `dev`. So, I would like for them to push to `dev`, but specifically the sub-directory within `dev` containing the source code, which all the regular contributors can pull down and test and work on etc, etc, etc.

Is this possible? How *should* I set something like this up? Should I be separating stuff out like this into separate repos?

Comment: If you're the only one pushing to `prod`, perhaps it would be better to clone it to a non-bare repo and replace the bare one with it. Then no one can push to it, and you can just pull `dev`'s changes into it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the workflows laid out in the Pro Git book chapter [5.1 Distributed Git - Distributed Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows). You could use the **Integration-Manager Workflow**. You'd have one blessed repository which everyone would pull from, but which no one could push to. The integrator would have push rights, and would pull changes from all devs, integrate them, and push them to that blessed repo. All repos would be the same (none would be `dev` or `prod`), and you could just ask people to work off of a `dev` branch, to make it a little easier to integrate things properly before merging them into `master`. This does put a lot of integration work on the person or persons in that role, but it also means at least one person maintains a really good overview of the whole project.

I do think it's pretty uncommon to use a submodule for production-ready code. That's really what branches are good at, and typically used for.